# Keyboard shortcut to access Chrome bookmarks (mac)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I seem to be almost entirely mouse-free at this point, minus being able to access the Bookmarks bar in Chrome with a keyboard shortcut! I've searched the web quite a bit for an answer, but to no avail....any ideas or workaround?

EDIT: Use Firefox. You can CMD + B --> will open Bookmarks navigator, and you can type to search, hit TAB, and then arrow through results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Holmes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/holmes/gokficnebmomagijbakglkcmhdbchbhn) is an extension that allows a shortcut activated bookmark search similar to Garrett's answer but without the "read and change all the data on any websites that you visit" permission.

Install the tool then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

[image: Screenshot of extension]

Answer (score 9):

If you are hoping to click on the actual bookmarks on your Google Chrome browser, using keyboard shortcuts, on Mac, you can make use of Mac's `Keyboard shortcuts` feature.

- Open `System settings` app
- Open `Shortcuts` section under `Keyboard`
- Choose `App shortcuts`
- Click `+`
- Choose `Google Chrome` as application
- On the title field, enter `Bookmarks->{Bookmark-name-goes-here}`
- Set a hotkey

[image: Setting a keyboard shortcut on Mac for Google Chrome bookmarks]

Save the changes and you can now use this hotkey to call that bookmark. This basically is setting a shortcut to your browser's menu item.

Comment: Works, thanks (Google Chrome v97)! If you are running a German macOS use "Lesezeichen" instead of "Bookmarks"

Answer (score 2):

`option` + `command` + `B` = Open Bookmarks Manager

You can utilize the **search bar** for fuzzy finding any particular page/folder

or,

`tab` and `arrow keys` to navigate through your bookmarks.

If you want to **open a folder** use `command` + `O` with the folder highlighted.  If the item is not highlighted, this will trigger the "Open File" shortcut.  You can highlight bookmark items/folders using `space` or arrow keys.

In addition, while highlighted you can open an entire folder of bookmarks by using the following:

`command` + `enter` = open all in new tabs on the same window

or,

`shift` + `enter` = open all in new tabs on a new window

Currently On Chrome Version 111.0.5563.64

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>

or

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this shortcut

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: That'll open the Bookmark Manager, and i can navigate to a folder of bookmarks, but then hitting enter on a bookmark doesnt open it lol

Comment: Guess I could copy the link and paste in url bar...this is a lot of work to open a page ugh there ought to be an easier way. thanks though

Comment: you can scroll through the links using the tab key and hitting enter opens the link

Comment: Do the above keyboard shortcut, and in the Bookmarks manager use tab to select something like Other Bookmarks, then hit space to open those bookmarks. Then tab over to those bookmarks, select the one you want, and click Cmd-Enter. That opens the page in a new tab. Apple has to be dragged screaming into keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a chrome plugin that is super useful and goes beyond what I was hoping for. It's called Bookmark Navigator. Here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-navigator/bfibpphfhdpgkmbpkfmhdiklgcfmmkha

Below is a picture of what it looks like. The tool is summoned with cmd + b, and then you can start typing to search all of your bookmarks. You can press enter to access the bookmark at top of list, or use arrow keys to navigate further down the list.

This is the fastest and most user friendly option I have found.

[image]

Comment: This looks great although the permission it needs to "read and change all the data on any websites that you visit" sounds a bit extreme for a bookmark manager.